# mysql: how can i remove the street number from a streetaddress column?

Tags: mysql, street-address

I have a column named streetaddress that contains

```
<Street Number> <Street Name>
```

for example:

```
15 rue Gontier-Patin
4968 Hillcrest Circle
```

how can i remove the numbers from the beginning of the row purely in sql?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about something like this - trim off everything up to and including the first space in strings which start with a number

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET addresscol=SUBSTRING(addresscol, LOCATE(' ', addresscol)+1)
WHERE addresscol REGEXP '^[0-9]';
```

Comment: Beware of special cases. A street number may contain additions like "15A" or "4968b" or "340-364".

Comment: None of those special cases would foil the approach given :)

But yes, any approach like this should be tested on the available data first!

Comment: Excellent use of the REGEXP and substring.  I actually used this in my order by clause to properly order the list of address for a customer so that the where essentially order by 'street' that was needed in a drop down.  The result came out very well.         SELECT propertyId, TRIM(address) 
FROM Properties
order by IF(address REGEXP '^[0-9]', SUBSTRING(address, LOCATE(' ', address)+1), address)

Answer (score 3):

This is based on @Paul Dixon above but is just for returning results without updating the data for things like sorting:

```
SELECT IF(address REGEXP '^[0-9]', SUBSTRING(address, LOCATE(' ', address)+1), address) AS addrSort FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not have regexp replace functions so it depends on the values in your column. If the string always begins with a number and then a space, you can do it with the SQl query Paul Dixon posted (doh, he was faster than me :D ).

If you need regular expressions to solve it, you have to do it in application code outside the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the job on the basis that each entry has it's street address seperated from the house number by a space (" ");

```
UPDATE table
SET streetaddress = MID(streetaddress, LOCATE(' ', streetaddress) + 1);
```

I've tested this and it works fine.

You can also use the following if you'd like to extract the house number to a new column previous to the update;

```
UPDATE table
SET housenumber = MID(streetaddress, 1, LOCATE(' ', streetaddress) - 1);
```